PCB Design review for STM32 USB-UART bridge
Could anyone review the schematic for CH340 chip. My goal is to drive STM32F030C8T6 automatically into bootloader mode while uploading code.
Unfortunately I am not able to program this board without manually (using onboard connectors) going into bootloader mode.
This is the error I am getting from STM32CubeProgrammer when trying to connect without entering manually to bootmode.

Here is the schematic used for CH340C


How would the CubeProgrammer know which pins to wiggle in order to go into bootloader? There is no sign of sending any sequence on the DTR/RTS pins, just that they are detected or set as high. Have you tried manually toggling the DTR and RTS pins in correct sequence to go into bootloader mode? There is nothing obvious in the schematic why it would not work.

Missing decoupling capacitors (multiple 100nF). Unclear info about VCC of U2. Is it 3.3V or 5V ? If 5V then double check input thresholds of U2, because TX signal from STM32 will be 3.3V logic in your case ... or consider using external pullups to VCC (5V) and GPIO open-drain mode on STM (selected pins are Five volt tolerant).

Thanks, VCC is 5V and decoupling caps are not shown in the picture but are actually in place. For the next rev I will replace VCC with 3.3V.
But according to datasheet, the logic levels should have worked with 5V also.
High-level Input Voltage [2.0 up to VCC+0.5 V]

The shown schematic seems incomplete.
But with what is shown, then decoupling on STM32 is missisng.
For reading purpose also put in power symbols and have these point in the right direction. It is nice to have signals coming from left to right. Also having power flowing from top to bottom.
Hope it makes sense.

Thanks! 4,7uf decoupling caps are actually in place. They are on a separate page
